# How to remove a string that left of character `;` and the contained string `U` and then display it?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and the values like this

```
000001U;000002;000003U;000004;000005U;000006U
```

and I want display the field is like

```
000002;000004;
```

Comment: What you would really need here is a regex replacement.  But SQL Server unfortunately does not support this out of the box.  You might be able to use a UDF.  But in general, you should not store your data unnormalized like this.

Comment: Here is a regex which you can use: `[0-9]{6}U;?` ... you may search for that, and then replace with empty string.

Comment: can u show an example how to use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Data nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT '000001U;000002;000003U;000004;000005U;000006U'

SELECT STUFF((SELECT '; '+Data
FROM
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS Data
FROM
(
SELECT 
   CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(Data,';','</S><S>') +'</S>' AS XML ) AS Data
 FROM @Table
)AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)dt 
WHERE CHARINDEX('U',Data)=0 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS Data
```

Result

```
 Data
 ---------
 000002; 000004
```

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server 2016 and later.

```
select  stuff (
               (select ',' + value
                from    STRING_SPLIT  ('000001U;000002;000003U;000004;000005U;000006U', ';')
                where   right(value, 1) <> 'U'
                 for    xml path('')), 
                1, 1, '')
```

for earlier version, you may use any CSV Spliter like this from Jeff Moden http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: i'm sorry i use sql server <2016 :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, SQL Server does not have any native regex replacement support.  But, if you can get a dump of your entire table/column, then you can easily do a regex replacement in another tool, such as Notepad++.

Do a find on this pattern:

```
[0-9]+U;?
```

And then just replace with empty string.  This should leave each row with the data you want to see.  Here is a demo showing that this works in Java.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to determine the value by `IsNumeric` function.

```
DECLARE @GIVEN VARCHAR(MAX)='000001U;000002;000003U;000004;000005U;000006U';
DECLARE @FINAL VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @FINAL =@FINAL+ case when ISNUMERIC(val)=1 then val+';' else '' end FROM (
SELECT split.x.value('.','varchar(max)') VAL FROM(
SELECT CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(@GIVEN,';','</M><M>')+'</M>'  AS XML) AS VAL
)A
CROSS APPLY a.VAL.nodes('/M') as split(x)
)AA

PRINT @FINAL
```

Result: `000002;000004;`